# promtool tsdb create-blocks-from openmetrics doesnt show

Tags: prometheus

I have a file like

```
# HELP process_cpu_user_seconds_total Total user CPU time spent in seconds.
# TYPE process_cpu_user_seconds_total counter
process_cpu_user_seconds_total{NODE_APP_INSTANCE="undefined",instance="127.0.0.1:9091",job="my_server"} 3.938 1689042066
# HELP process_cpu_system_seconds_total Total system CPU time spent in seconds.
# TYPE process_cpu_system_seconds_total counter
process_cpu_system_seconds_total{NODE_APP_INSTANCE="undefined",instance="127.0.0.1:9091",job="my_server"} 0.593 1689042066
# HELP nodejs_gc_duration_seconds Garbage collection duration by kind, one of major, minor, incremental or weaken.
# TYPE nodejs_gc_duration_seconds histogram
nodejs_gc_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.001",kind="minor",NODE_APP_INSTANCE="undefined",instance="127.0.0.1:9091",job="my_server"} 8 1689042066
# EOF
```

I use `promtool tsdb create-blocks-from openmetrics ./the.prom ./data` to push this metrics into tsdb,

result is

```
BLOCK ULID                  MIN TIME       MAX TIME       DURATION     NUM SAMPLES  NUM CHUNKS   NUM SERIES   SIZE
01H51E3HM7YJ90DJ72THJ20QX2  1689042066000  1689042066001  1ms          3            3            3            1419
```

and i copy the data to the prometheus data.
and i can use `promtool tsdb dump` to see that my metrics is in the tsdb file

```
{NODE_APP_INSTANCE="undefined", __name__="nodejs_gc_duration_seconds_bucket", instance="localhost:9091", job="my_server", kind="minor", le="0.001"} 8 1689042066000
{NODE_APP_INSTANCE="undefined", __name__="process_cpu_system_seconds_total", instance="localhost:9091", job="my_server"} 0.593 1689042066000
{NODE_APP_INSTANCE="undefined", __name__="process_cpu_user_seconds_total", instance="localhost:9091", job="my_server"} 3.938 1689042066000
```

but i cannot search this metrics in prometheus and grafana. how to make it work?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I use the docker image. The data folder (e.g. "01H6APG95T79B6XRS3HH0GJBM9") should be copied to /prometheus, so it becomes /prometheus/01H6APG95T79B6XRS3HH0GJBM9

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not making the UI run the right query.

The data you loaded only spans `1ms`, the default resolution and range on prometheus UI `Graph` are not suited for this. You cannot see it under `Table` either because the metric will always be in the past.

You should specify the timestamp of the sample under `Evaluation time` on prometheus `Table`, this will help the UI make the right query:

```
curl 'http://$PROEMTHEUS/api/v1/query?query=nodejs_gc_duration_seconds_bucket&time=1689042066'
```

(if the above query returns nothing, you'll probably need to wait/make prometheus take the new blocks into account)

If you load data that spans longer periods, you should see them easily on prometheus `Graph`.

Comment: The same should apply to grafana.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think loaded data spans only 1ms (not even 1s, since provided timestamp is in seconds)? Wouldn't standard 5-minute staleness rule apply to loaded data too?

Comment: Take a look at the provided command's output.
Provided timestamp is in second but only one timestamp was loaded.
staleness doesn't apply as that Prometheus instance doesn't know anything about the target and nothing in the loaded data gives an indication about staleness.